# What's in it for Tamaki?

Tags: plot-explanation, ouran-high-school

In Ouran High School Host Club, Tamaki decides to make Haruhi a host in place of paying off her 8 million yen debt.

If she had continued on as an errand boy, the debt would have been paid off eventually... even if it took years.

The hosts don't charge any of their customers, and even if they did... Tamaki tells Haruhi she only needs to get 100 customers for her debt to be erased, and unless they were charging a fortune 100 customers wouldn't even come close to paying off her debt.

So, what's in this deal for Tamaki? At the time of the 100 customer arrangement he's not attracted to her, he still thinks she's a boy. So it can't be that he just wants to keep her around.

Is it a personal challenge for Tamaki to see if he can train the "commoner" well enough to get 100 customers?

What's his reasoning?

Comment: Why do you think the hosts don't charge? Where else do they get the money for their elaborate events?

Comment: No, I know they don't charge the ladies, and I know a lot of their money comes from Kyoya's little side projects (picture books, etc.). I just don't understand Tamaki's reasoning for bringing Haruhi on as a host instead of leaving her as an errand boy. Since there won't be much of a financial gain to be made from it. Unless they just want another host to help bring in more ladies. I suppose, that's the reason in it's simplest terms.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm trying to remember... I'd always assumed they thought she was cute and fit a niche they didn't have... I don't remember the order of events in the first episode that well, apparently.

Comment: "I'd always assumed they thought she was cute and fit a niche they didn't have."   ..... Truth be told, that is the reason. lol. I was just a little confused as Tamaki wasn't aware that she was a girl at that point. So, attraction kinda went out the window for me as one of his reasons, but I believe he's slightly confused himself by his attraction to her when he thinks she's a boy. Unless, the reason is that he really did want to challenge himself and fix up the "commoner." Idk, I guess I'm reaching for a more in depth answer than what there really is lol. :)

Comment: That's one of the unique things about *Ouran*... most "hidden gender" anime/manga involve people who are hiding from everyone, including the other main characters, who often find out much later... but with *Ouran*, all of the main characters know from the... second (?) episode on, they're just dealing with helping her hide it... which makes it fun. Oh, and the lightbulb reveal is my favorite thing... It's such a cute way of showing when the guys "get it".

Comment: It's a great show so far, I'm only about halfway through at this point. I'm very, very new to anime. I think the way that an anime series tells a story just takes some getting used to. l find myself overthinking a lot of things. lol

Comment: Ah, yeah... get used to it. Things get a bit absurd through the middle but it's always fun. Just an FYI, if you're not aware, there's actually a dedicated Anime SE. The questions are totally on topic here and we won't ever tell you to go there instead, just thought I'd point it out. They and their chat room are a great resource for "recommended viewing" and in-depth understanding of Anime.

Comment: I believe in the Manga, after chatting with Haruhi, Tameki comes to the incorrect conclusion that Haruhi is already a slave to the rich, having to cook and clean for them. Haruhi tells him that's incorrect, but Tameki feels bad for making her the club's dog and decides to make her a host. I think the anime sort of glosses over this. But no, there certainly wouldn't be any large financial gain to make. No more so than what Kyoya gets off the other hosts from pictures and such. So, what's Tamaki's reasoning in the anime? Ego? The challenge, perhaps? Idk,a and I don't think it's ever said.

Comment: @Stephen_Film_Guy Considering how rich they all are, I doubt that amount of money means anything significant to them anyway.